Collection expression inside collection initializer vs. compiler
In C#,  this collection expression does not compile with a list collection initializer (in my opinion, everything should be in place to make it work, but the Roslyn developers must have their reasons):
var list = new List<int[]>
{
    [ 1, 2 ] // Compiler error CS1501
};
list.Add([1, 2]); // Although semantically equivalent, this compiles

My question is: Why does it suddenly work when wrapping the collection expression in another expression (by putting parentheses around it)? Because, indeed, this compiles:
var list = new List<int[]>
{
    ([ 1, 2 ]) // Works
};

Why does the compiler seem to get smarter when the collection expression is placed inside an extra expression? Is this some sort of magic cast? Probably not, because here the collection expression doesn't automatically get turned into Array<int>:
var arr = ([1, 2]); // Compiler error CS9176


Possibly because [1, 2, etc.] is the syntax for indicating indices in an initializer, like new Matrix { [1, 2] = 9 } and the compiler is interpreting your [1, 2] as an unfinished expression of that syntax. Wrapping the array expression in parentheses resolves the ambiguity. What is the actual compiler error (not just the error code)?

@JLRishe Yes, it seems to have to do with some indexing interpretation. The error message starts with "Cannot resolve indexer '!.default.Property(int, int)', candidates are:[...]"

It's very likely because we use the object-initializer syntax and the indexer [] is a special kind of a property-like member (I think it is the default one - called Item)
So when you normally write list[0] = 3, it's as if you wrote list.Item(0) = 3
Short demo code with a class with an indexer:
public class Foo {
    private int[] arr = new int[100];
    
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    
    // public int Item(int i)
    public int this[int i]
    {
        get { return arr[i]; }
        set { arr[i] = value; }
    }
}

void Main() {
    var foo = new Foo {
        [0] = 42, // Item(0) = 42
        [1] = 43, // Item(1) = 43
        Bar = 3
    };
}

So, when the compiler encounters [ it's thinking Item is going to be set (looks for properties/member names such as Bar or [x])
In your case with List<int[]>, when you add the parenthesis ( which is invalid character to use for a member, is that it figures out, it's actually the new collection syntax. Before that it tries to make sure it gets a valid setter expression [0] = 3.
It's funny because for a List this is always a compile-time valid syntax, but guaranteed a runtime error (even if we set the capacity):
var baz = new List<int[]>(10) {
    [0] = [1,2,3],
    [1] = [4,5,6]
};

What you can do is go all the way with the new syntax:
List<int[]> baz = [
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6]
];

or
var bar = (List<int[]>) [
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6]
];

